# WordPress: Disabling Default Styles @ load-styles.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress project that requires me to remove the default styles from the wp-admin area. I know of ways of INSERTING into the load-styles.php script but not REMOVING. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
function remove_default_stylesheets() {
    wp_deregister_style('wp-admin');
}
add_action('admin_init','remove_default_stylesheets');
```

Paste this code in your `functions.php` and your admin panel will be styleless (only WordPress' default stylesheets will be removed).